# "Can't create reliable connection to server" error while signin using google plus

Tags: android, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am developing an application in which i want sign in  using google plus.
I have follow the steps from 
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

But when i try to sign in to google plus using google api sample projects(imported from android sdk->extras->google services)
it always show  **"Can't create reliable connection to server"**.

How can i solve it?
i am testing the sample on real device.

My logcat is as follows,

```
05-17 15:21:56.500: E/GLSUser(6721): Empty consent data
05-17 15:21:56.500: I/GLSUser(6721): GLS error: NetworkError testid.android@gmail.com oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
05-17 15:21:56.500: W/GLSUser(6721): Status from wire: NetworkError status: NETWORK_ERROR
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When following the code example at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in, I got "Empty consent data" as well.

But calling `setScopes()` on the `PlusClient` instance seemed to solve the problem:

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
            .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity")
            .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE)
            .build();
```

Have you set scopes in your code example?

Comment: Solved my problem too!!! I have made two mistake first is "different package name" and second is not mentioning the "scope".

Answer (score 1):

in my case the problem was that my real device was not connected to internet.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/host file on your device. 
Comment everything except

```
120.0.0.1 localhost
```

Put # in front of the line to comment it. 
Note that you need root access to edit this file.