# INVALID_KEY message trying to authenticate through the Google+ Sign in Button

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I am trying to authenticate the user following [this gist by Ian Barber](https://gist.github.com/ianbarber/5170508). The button asks for the user account, but it never gets to show the authorization dialog and instead exits with the message "An internal error ocurred". Logcat shows this:

```
W/GLSUser ( 4353): Status from wire: INVALID_KEY status: null
W/GLSUser ( 4353): Status from wire: INVALID_KEY status: null
E/GLSUser ( 4353): Empty consent data
I/GLSUser ( 4353): GLS error: INVALID_KEY icoloma@gmail.com oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
W/GLSUser ( 4353): Status from wire: Unknown status: UNKNOWN
```

The certificate used to sign my app is the same configured at my Google API Console page, and the package name is also the same.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This happens when your certificate has been added in the "Simple API Access" section instead of "Client ID for installed applications". In the [Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) of your project click "Create an OAUTH2 client ID" (NOT "Create new Android Key"), select "Android" and introduce your SHA1 and package.

Comment: This seemed to work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606155/cant-create-reliable-connection-to-server-error-while-signin-using-google-plu

Comment: God, I got trolled so hard by this. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similiar error:

```
772-799/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSUser﹕ GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
05-21 13:23:50.231      772-799/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSActivity﹕ [art] Status from wire: INVALID_KEY status: null
05-21 13:23:50.231      772-799/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSActivity﹕ [art] Status from wire: INVALID_KEY status: null
05-21 13:23:50.235      772-799/com.google.process.gapps I/GLSUser﹕ GLS error: INVALID_KEY my-gmail@address.com oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
05-21 13:23:50.235      772-799/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSActivity﹕ [art] Status from wire: Unknown status: UNKNOWN
```

I fixed it by signing the APK using a keystore I generated. The keystore SHA was added to our Google Developer console.

Comment: the same problem please help

Answer (score 0):

One more reason why this error occurs:

If you have a sub-package, ensure you only mention your application's main package in the developer's console, not the sub-package.

ex: If your App is under `com.example.myapp`,  if your G+ login activity is under package `com.example.myapp.authentication`, in the developer's console, the package name you enter should be **com.example.myapp**  (leave out the subpackage)

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error occurred *probably* because I used sha256withrsa algorithm to sign my APK instead of sha1withrsa. Probably - I don't know for certain as I will not change my signature keys just because Google API is dumb.