# INVALID_KEY error trying to authenticate through the Google+ Sign in Button

Tags: android

I am trying to authenticate the user following [this gist by Ian Barber][1]. The button asks for the user account, but it never gets to show the authorization dialog and instead exits with the message "An internal error ocurred". Logcat shows this:

```
W/GLSUser ( 4353): Status from wire: INVALID_KEY status: null
W/GLSUser ( 4353): Status from wire: INVALID_KEY status: null
E/GLSUser ( 4353): Empty consent data
I/GLSUser ( 4353): GLS error: INVALID_KEY oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
W/GLSUser ( 4353): Status from wire: Unknown status: UNKNOWN
```

The certificate used to sign my app is the same configured at my Google API Console page, and the package name is also the same.

[INVALID_KEY message trying to authenticate through the Google+ Sign in Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734114/invalid-key-message-trying-to-authenticate-through-the-google-sign-in-button)

The post below has the solution to this which doesnt work for me.

I dont know what is the problem. Please help.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606155/cant-create-reliable-connection-to-server-error-while-signin-using-google-plu

Answer (score 0):

One more reason why this error occurs:

If you have a sub-package, ensure you only mention your application's main package in the developer's console, not the sub-package.

ex: If your App is under `com.example.myapp`,  if your G+ login activity is under package `com.example.myapp.authentication`, in the developer's console, the package name you enter should be `com.example.myapp` (leave out the subpackage)